# Can I give internet access to a azure VM, without a public IP?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network

I have 3 debian VM on azure, one of them have a public IP with which it goes online (VM_1), and the others only have the internal network(VM_2, VM_3).

Can I give access to my VM_2 or VM_3, through the VM_1?

What broke me was to see that VM_1 has 2 network interfaces, private and public, but if I enter the configuration file there are only 2 interfaces, lo and eth0, and eth0 contains the private IP...

Can i do something, or i need to pay for another public IP assigned by azure?

I want to add some info: 
[My subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkCow.png)

VM_1 with public and private IP, can download files.

VM_2 and 3, with private IP but without Public IP, can't.

Comment: define `give access`?

Comment: Yes, I wanted to say if I can use VM_1 as a forward, to go online with VM_2

Comment: what do you mean `go online`? vms in azure have outbound connectivity to internet by default (even without PIP)

Comment: Well, so if i have internet connectivity by default, why, having the same configuration, VM_2 can't even reach it? I have reviewed /etc/resolv.conf in VM_1 and VM_2, they have the same content. I need to check other files?

Comment: well, i have no idea what you are trying to do, but vms without public ip in azure can connect to the internet by default. why it doesnt work for you? I have no idea. you might have misconfigured the vm, or the firewall, or NSG, or UDR, or Azure Firewall, etc

Comment: What do you mean that access the VM_2 and VM_3 without public IP? SSH or HTTP request?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is possible via [Azure Virtual NAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/nat-overview). You can assign IPs to the NAT gateway and in the subnet you reference the NAT gateway. By this way all the VMs in the subnet can reach Internet via the NAT gateway IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

From azure docs:

*In Azure, virtual machines created in a virtual network without explicit outbound connectivity defined are assigned a **default outbound public IP address**. This IP address enables outbound connectivity from the resources to the Internet. This access is referred to as default outbound access.*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/ip-services/default-outbound-access
Problem with other vms connectivity might be because of the VM1 having public attached to the same subnet together with VM2/VM3, as it stats:

*The conditions for programming default outbound access for a VM instance are as follows:

1. **All NICs in the same group, which is either VM, Availability Set, or VMSS, must not be associated with Standard PIP, Standard Public LB, or NAT Gateway.**
2. It must not be a part of VMSS with flexible orchestration mode.

***On 30 September 2025, default outbound access connectivity for virtual machines in Azure will be retired**. After this date, all new VMs that require internet access will need to use explicit outbound connectivity methods such as Azure NAT Gateway, Azure Load Balancer outbound rules, or a directly attached Azure public IP address.*
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/default-outbound-access-for-vms-in-azure-will-be-retired-transition-to-a-new-method-of-internet-access/